# singularity run error: No valid /bin/sh in container

Tags: sh, singularity-container

I have a singularity image and convert the sig file to a sandbox format.  After changing some scripts, a modified new sig file was rebuilt with a sandbox. But when I run the sandbox or sig image, error report like below:

*ERROR: No valid /bin/sh in container*

*ABORT  : Retval = 255*

command line

`singularity build --sandbox test_sandbox/ test.sig`

`singularity  shell test_sandbox`

/bin/sh exactly do not exist in test_sandbox. Why the /bin folder is empty when build sandbox from sig file?

Answer (score 0):

For me [this suggestion](https://groups.google.com/a/lbl.gov/d/msg/singularity/jUdi9aHKTgo/rTs8nNF9BwAJ) did the trick: when changing Singularity versions, configuration, or installation path, run `make clean` between `make` and `make install` in the installation process.

Comment: thx. I will try this at local. It's unable to operate the system Singularity for non-root user.

Comment: This tip applies to building from sources, but how to fix when installing from linux packages?